# How to make textboxes go back to being blank

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a teacher login page below where the teacher enters in their username and password and it will check in the database if the details entered are valid or not. Below is the code:

```
<body>

<?php

$username="xxx";
$password="xxx";
$database="mobile_app";

mysql_connect('localhost',$username,$password);

@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

foreach (array('teacherusername','teacherpassword') as $varname) {
        $$varname = (isset($_POST[$varname])) ? $_POST[$varname] : '';
      }

?>

<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" id="teachLoginForm">        
<p>Username</p><p><input type="text" name="teacherusername" value="<?php echo $teacherusername; ?>" /></p>      <!-- Enter Teacher Username-->
<p>Password</p><p><input type="password" name="teacherpassword" value="<?php echo $teacherpassword; ?>" /></p>  <!-- Enter Teacher Password--> 
<p><input id="loginSubmit" type="submit" value="Login" name="submit" /></p>
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$query = "
SELECT * FROM Teacher t  
WHERE 
(t.TeacherUsername = '".mysql_real_escape_string($teacherusername)."')
AND
(t.TeacherPassword = '".mysql_real_escape_string($teacherpassword)."')
";


$num = mysql_num_rows($result = mysql_query($query));

$loged = false;

session_start(); 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {

      if ($_POST['teacherusername'] == ($row['TeacherUsername']) && $_POST['teacherpassword'] == ($row['TeacherPassword']))
      {
          $loged = true;
      }

$_SESSION['teacherforename'] = $row['TeacherForename'];
$_SESSION['teachersurname'] = $row['TeacherSurname'];

  }

  if ($loged == true){
  header( 'Location: menu.php' ) ;
}else{
  echo "The Username or Password that you Entered is not Valid. Try Entering it Again.";
}

mysql_close();

}
 ?>


</body>
```

My question is that if the user gets thier login details incorrect and submits it, how can I get it so that it removes the password in password textbox so that the textbox is blank for the user to re-ener in their password.

Also if the user refreshes the browser, I want both the username textbox and password textbox to both go blank. Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Please don't store unhashed passwords in your database. That's a basic security rule.

Comment: Outta be able to find a nice example here. http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=115284

Comment: Just out of interest, what would happen if I entered a username of "</form><script language="javascript">while(true){ alert("SPAM"); }</script><form>"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 matters here, first is the population of the password field on failure.

To make the password field go blank simply change this:

`<p>Password</p><p><input type="password" name="teacherpassword" value="<?php echo $teacherpassword; ?>" /></p>  <!-- Enter Teacher Password-->`

to this

`<p>Password</p><p><input type="password" name="teacherpassword" /></p>  <!-- Enter Teacher Password-->`

All you're doing is removing the PHP `echo` of the password field `value`.

Now the refresh, as the form is being submitted to the same page, when the refresh button or F5 button is being pushed the browser will confirm if the user wants to re-submit the data.

To get around this, in the rare case where it is a problem for me, I submit the form to another page (e.g. dologin.php) to handle the submission and then redirect back to the form on an error with an error code and any information you want to be re-populated in the URL that can be shown to the user. Be cautious about what you're passing in the URL, for example don't put the password there or anything that may be sensitive.

Then when the F5 button is pushed or refresh clicked there is no earlier submission for the browser to re-submit.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Glad to help! Good luck with the rest of your app :-)

Answer (score 2):

You are explicitly setting the value of the password field on the following line:

```
<input type="password" name="teacherpassword" value="<?php echo $teacherpassword; ?>" />
```

If you just leave the `value` attribute blank, or remove it altogether, and it should come back blank after a failed login attempt. Like this:

```
<input type="password" name="teacherpassword" />
```

Now, there is something strange about your PHP script: you seem to be double-checking the login info, which is not necessary. First, you check the database for rows where the passed credentials match. After that, you loop the results, and check again if the values returned match the posted data. This last step seems unnecessary! So, you can replace the whole `while(){}` block with this:

```
if($num == 1) { // there should be one one user per username
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $_SESSION['teacherforename'] = $row['TeacherForename'];
    $_SESSION['teachersurname'] = $row['TeacherSurname'];
    $loged = true;
}
```

Comment: Can I ask which step you are refering to (show code for which step)? Are you saying I do not need this `value="<?php echo $teacherpassword; ?>`?

Answer (score 1):

**Change**

```
if ($loged == true) {
    header('Location: menu.php');
} else {
    echo "The Username or Password that you Entered is not Valid. Try Entering it Again.";
}
```

**To**

```
if ($loged == true) {
    header('Location: menu.php');
} else {
    echo "The Username or Password that you Entered is not Valid. Try Entering it Again.";
    $teacherpassword = '';
}
```

EDIT: Also move your form so it renders right after the said if statement.

Comment: This won't do anything. By the time `$teacherpassword` is set to blank, it has already been used to set the initial textbox value.

Comment: @Travesty3 - You're right, it would be best then to move the HTML form after this if statement.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you can also set the $_POST variables so you can easily do it with `$_POST['username'] = '';` but you'll have to have the form output after you've done the processing.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

first give id to your password input box

```
<input type="password" name="teacherpassword" id="teacherpassword" value="<?php echo $teacherpassword; ?>" />
```

and then change your else code like below

```
else{
  print "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('The Username or Password that you Entered is not Valid. Try Entering it Again.'); document.getElementById('teacherpassword').value=''; window.location.relod(true);</script>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you have it is a bit overcomplicated and kinda backwards. Try this:

```
<body>
<?php
    $username="xxx"; 
    $password="xxx"; 
    $database="mobile_app";
    mysql_connect('localhost', $username, $password); 

    @mysql_select_db($database) or die("Unable to select database"); 

    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $query = "
            SELECT TeacherForename, TeacherSurname
            FROM Teacher
            WHERE
                (TeacherUsername = '". mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["teacherusername"]) ."')
                AND (TeacherPassword = '". mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["teacherpassword"]) ."')"; 

        $result = mysql_query($query));
        if ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['teacherforename'] = $row['TeacherForename']; 
            $_SESSION['teachersurname'] = $row['TeacherSurname'];

            header('Location: menu.php');
            die();
        }
        else
            echo "The Username or Password that you Entered is not Valid. Try Entering it Again.";

        mysql_close(); 
    }
?> 
    <form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" id="teachLoginForm">         
        <p>Username</p><p><input type="text" name="teacherusername" value="<?php echo $teacherusername; ?>" /></p>      <!-- Enter Teacher Username--> 
        <p>Password</p><p><input type="password" name="teacherpassword" /></p>  <!-- Enter Teacher Password-->  
        <p><input id="loginSubmit" type="submit" value="Login" name="submit" /></p> 
    </form>
</body>
```